# how to connect debian vmware from putty on the same pc

Tags: vmware-player, ssh, debian, putty

i install debian on vmware player , and its working fine 
now i like to connect with my putty to the vmware debian
but i dont know how , when i do ifconfig -a 
im getting only my router inner network ip 
what do i need to do to connect to the vmware on the same pc

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit difficult to parse.

If your host computer is pulling DHCP from somewhere you can have the VM do the same thing such that it gets an IP address you can connect to.

If VMware player permits you to select "bridged" networking (it's been too long since I've used 'Player' to recall), do so. In your Debian VM, either reboot or release/renew your DHCP lease (I'm not familiar with the Debian "contrivance" to do that-- I'm a RedHat/Fedora/CentOS guy). You should see the VM pull an IP address from the same DHCP server your PC is. At that point, your PC (or any other PC on that network, for that matter) should be able to communicate with SSH, etc, with the Debian VM (assuming, obviously, a listening SSH server and permissive firewall rules in the VM).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set it up so that your VM gets a unique IP address. Then you should be able to connect to it.

Comment: how? do i do that , i know that when i start the sun virtual box
i do get unique ip

Comment: So, when you're in your host OS do an ipconfig or ifconfig, note the IP address. Then when you're in the VM do the same thing, depending on how you setup your network (bridged or whatever) you should get a different IP. Give more details of the software you're using for exact instructions.